# Pyodbc - Web.py blocking connection

Tags: pyodbc, web.py

I am currently using PYODBC in Web.py to connect to a SQL Azure DB and so far all was well. We recently added a new call into our Web.py URL list which made a cursor call like follows

```
class get_teas:
        def GET(self):

            con = pyodbc.connect(con_string,timeout=120)
            con.timeout = 120
            cur =  con.cursor()

            for row in cur.execute("{CALL get_all_tea_in_china ("+user_data.theother+",'"+user_data.this+"','"+user_data.that+"')}"):

                   ...do some dictionary stuff

            cur.commit();
            cur.close()
            return 'DONE'
```

However we have recently noticed due to get_all_tea_in_china being a long call that it is blocking all subsequent calls within web.py which is not great for hopefully obvious reasons! Is there a way of making it such that this call is not blocking?

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `celery`,put your long call in a asynchronous task queue.http://www.celeryproject.org/